# Contact form within a Boostrap pop-up modal window

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, contact-form

I am using bootstrap to open up a modal form.

I really cannot figure out what is going on. This code works in other projects (http://phpform.webitwebsites.co.nz/newtest/) and sends the mail no problem. But if I copy it into my website, it is like my submit button is unresponsive and it doesn't load the initiate quote.php file.
Here is a live version where it is not working
http://phpform.webitwebsites.co.nz/test/

My HTML:

```
<button href="#freeQuote" role="button" data-toggle="modal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" style="font-size:16px;">Free Quote</button>
</center>
<div class="modal fade" id="freeQuote">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">FREE Quote</h3>

    </div>
    <!-- close modal-header -->
    <div class="modal-body">
            <h4>Send us a description </h4>
        <hr>
        <form name="contact" method="post" action="quote.php">
            <label for="name">Your Name</label>
            <br>
            <input class="col-md-10" type="text" name="name" class="input-xlarge">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="company">Your Company</label>
            <br>
            <input class="col-md-10" type="text" name="company" class="input-xlarge">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="email">Your E-mail</label>
            <br>
            <input class="col-md-10" type="email" name="email" class="input-xlarge">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="message">Details</label>
            <br>
            <textarea class="col-md-10" name="message" class="input-xlarge"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input class="btn-sm btn-success" type="submit" value="Send!" id="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- close modal-body -->
```

My PHP

```
<?php
$myemail = 'example@gmail.com';
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $company = strip_tags ($_POST['company']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
    echo "<span class=\"alert alert-success\" >Your message has been received. Thanks! Here is what you submitted:</span><br><br>";
    echo "<stong>Name:</strong> ".$name."<br>";   
    echo "<strong>Company:</strong> " .$company . "<br>";
    echo "<stong>Email:</strong> ".$email."<br>"; 
    echo "<stong>Message:</strong> ".$message."<br>";

    //generate email and send!
    $to = $myemail;
    $email_subject = "New Quote form submission";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
    "Email: $email\n Message \n $message";
    $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
}
?>
```

Comment: clicking button in http://phpform.webitwebsites.co.nz/test/ sends request in process.php not in qoute.php

Comment: check console log fire error  " g is undefined"

Comment: Whenever I click the button on your site it gives a javascript error. I'm guessing some js code on your page is blocking the submit request

Comment: Thanks, there is a conflict with some of the javascript.